# How can I pass a list of names to list.select?

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation

Assume I want to use `list.select` function from `rlist` package to select two fields.

```
x <- list(p1 = list(type='A',score=list(c1=10,c2=8)),
      p2 = list(type='B',score=list(c1=9,c2=9)),
      p3 = list(type='B',score=list(c1=9,c2=7)))
```

rather than using this syntax:

```
list.select(x, type, score)
```

I want to use something list this, but it doesn't work:

```
param <- c("type", "score")
list.select(x, param)
```

Comment: It works for me. Would you mind to explain why it does not work for you?

Comment: @JilberUrbina no, the return of the `param` attempt is a list of char vectors of type and score. OP wants to programatically pass in arguments because their names may not be known in advance.

Comment: Don't you wish splicing `!!!` works outside of the `tidyverse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to do it using `list.select`, but here is a `purrr` solution:

```
library(purrr)

param <- c("type", "score")
map(x, `[`, param)
```

this obviously also works with `lapply`:

```
lapply(x, `[`, param)
```

but if you have a deeper nested list of lists, use `modify_depth`:

```
modify_depth(x, 1, `[`, param)
```

the `.depth` argument can be adjusted to go deeper down the hierarchy.

**Output:**

```
$p1
$p1$type
[1] "A"

$p1$score
$p1$score$c1
[1] 10

$p1$score$c2
[1] 8


$p2
$p2$type
[1] "B"

$p2$score
$p2$score$c1
[1] 9

$p2$score$c2
[1] 9


$p3
$p3$type
[1] "B"

$p3$score
$p3$score$c1
[1] 9

$p3$score$c2
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hackish way using `eval(parse(.))` but the result is not identical to your solution. The pieces are there, though.

```
> str(list.select(x, do.call(c, sapply(param, FUN = function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))))
List of 3
 $ p1:List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ type    : chr "A"
  .. ..$ score.c1: num 10
  .. ..$ score.c2: num 8
 $ p2:List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ type    : chr "B"
  .. ..$ score.c1: num 9
  .. ..$ score.c2: num 9
 $ p3:List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ type    : chr "B"
  .. ..$ score.c1: num 9
  .. ..$ score.c2: num 7
> str(list.select(x, type, score))
List of 3
 $ p1:List of 2
  ..$ type : chr "A"
  ..$ score:List of 2
  .. ..$ c1: num 10
  .. ..$ c2: num 8
 $ p2:List of 2
  ..$ type : chr "B"
  ..$ score:List of 2
  .. ..$ c1: num 9
  .. ..$ c2: num 9
 $ p3:List of 2
  ..$ type : chr "B"
  ..$ score:List of 2
  .. ..$ c1: num 9
  .. ..$ c2: num 7
```